# How do I handle Python unicode strings with null-bytes the 'right' way?

Tags: python, winapi, unicode, pywin32

**Question**

It seems that PyWin32 is comfortable with giving null-terminated unicode strings as return values. I would like to deal with these strings the 'right' way.

Let's say I'm getting a string like: `u'C:\\Users\\Guest\\MyFile.asy\x00\x00sy'`. This appears to be a C-style null-terminated string hanging out in a Python unicode object. I want to trim this bad boy down to a regular ol' string of characters that I could, for example, display in a window title bar.

Is trimming the string off at the first null byte the right way to deal with it?

I didn't expect to get a return value like this, so I wonder if I'm missing something important about how Python, Win32, and unicode play together... or if this is just a PyWin32 bug.

**Background**

I'm using the Win32 file chooser function [`GetOpenFileNameW`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.7/pywin32/win32gui__GetSaveFileNameW_meth.html) from the PyWin32 package. According to the documentation, this function returns a tuple containing the full filename path as a Python unicode object.

When I open the dialog with an existing path and filename set, I get a strange return value.

For example I had the default set to: `C:\\Users\\Guest\\MyFileIsReallyReallyReallyAwesome.asy`

In the dialog I changed the name to `MyFile.asy` and clicked save.

The full path part of the return value was: u'C:\Users\Guest\MyFile.asy\x00wesome.asy'`

I expected it to be: `u'C:\\Users\\Guest\\MyFile.asy'`

The function is returning a recycled buffer without trimming off the terminating bytes. Needless to say, the rest of my code wasn't set up for handling a C-style null-terminated string.

**Demo Code**

The following code demonstrates null-terminated string in return value from GetSaveFileNameW.

Directions: In the dialog change the filename to 'MyFile.asy' then click Save. Observe what is printed to the console. The output I get is `u'C:\\Users\\Guest\\MyFile.asy\x00wesome.asy'`.

```
import win32gui, win32con

if __name__ == "__main__":
    initial_dir = 'C:\\Users\\Guest'
    initial_file = 'MyFileIsReallyReallyReallyAwesome.asy'
    filter_string = 'All Files\0*.*\0'
    (filename, customfilter, flags) = \
        win32gui.GetSaveFileNameW(InitialDir=initial_dir,
                    Flags=win32con.OFN_EXPLORER, File=initial_file,
                    DefExt='txt', Title="Save As", Filter=filter_string,
                    FilterIndex=0)
    print repr(filename)
```

Note: If you don't shorten the filename enough (for example, if you try MyFileIsReally.asy) the string will be complete without a null byte.

**Environment**

Windows 7 Professional 64-bit (no service pack), Python 2.7.1, PyWin32 Build 216

**UPDATE: PyWin32 Tracker Artifact**

Based on the comments and answers I have received so far, this is likely a pywin32 bug so I filed a [tracker artifact](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3277647&group_id=78018&atid=551954).

**UPDATE 2: Fixed!**

Mark Hammond reported in the tracker artifact that this is indeed a bug. A fix was checked in to rev f3fdaae5e93d, so hopefully that will make the next release.

I think Aleksi Torhamo's answer below is the best solution for versions of PyWin32 before the fix.

Comment: +1 Huh, seems like you found a PyWin32 bug!

Comment: I have dropped Mark Hammond (the primary PyWin32 maintainer) a quick note referring him to this page.

Comment: @Tom Thanks! I also filed a tracker artifact here: https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3277647&group_id=78018&atid=551954

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say it's a bug. The right way to deal with it would probably be fixing pywin32, but in case you aren't feeling adventurous enough, just trim it.

You can get everything before the first `'\x00'` with `filename.split('\x00', 1)[0]`.

Comment: You're correct, Mark Hammond (the PyWin32 maintainer) confirmed it was a bug and fixed it in Rev f3fdaae5e93d, so I think that should make it fixed in the next release. See https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3277647&group_id=78018&atid=551954

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't happen on the version of PyWin32/Windows/Python I tested; I don't get any nulls in the returned string even if it's very short.  You might investigate if a newer version of one of the above fixes the bug.

Comment: What is your configuration? I'm using Python 2.7.1 and PyWin32 Build 216 (the latest) on Windows 7 Pro (no service pack).

Comment: I'm using Python 2.6.5 on Windows 7 Enterprise x64 with the same PyWin32 build.  Maybe it's a 32 vs 64-bit thing?

Comment: Actually, I'm on 64-bit Windows as well. I am not using a 64-bit Python build though.

Comment: Aha, that might be it. I am using a 64-bit Python (and Win 7 SP1 which I had forgotten to mention). In any case, definitely sounds like a PyWin32 issue that's worth reporting.

Answer (score 0):

ISTR that I had this issue some years ago, then I discovered that such Win32 filename-dialog-related functions return a sequence of `'filename1\0filename2\0...filenameN\0\0'`, while including possible garbage characters depending on the buffer that Windows allocated.

Now, you might prefer a list instead of the raw return value, but that would be a RFE, not a bug.

PS When I had this issue, I quite understood why one would expect `GetOpenFileName` to possibly return a list of filenames, while I couldn't imagine why `GetSaveFileName` would. Perhaps this is considered as API uniformity. Who am I to know, anyway?

Comment: Hi ΤΖΩΤΖΙΟΥ, the null-separated sequence for multiple filename selections is documented behavior, so it's not really an issue. The problem described in my question was with single filename selection. In such a case I wouldn't expect there to be null characters since the documentation says the returned value will be "the full path". I filed a tracker artifact for the bug, and it has now been fixed in the development code, along with clarified documentation.