# python string comparison (==) not working

Tags: python, string, comparison

Why the following String comparison is not working?
I have the following code (I adapted it to make is simpler). I retrieve a player from the database and add it to a list of players. Then I loop on the list of player and try to find it, and even tho' the string is the same, the comparison return false..

```
def findPlayer2(self, protocol, playerId):
    cur = self.conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT playerId, playerName, rating FROM players WHERE playerId LIKE (%s)", [playerId])
    nbResult = cur.rowcount
    result = cur.fetchone()
    cur.close()

    if nbResult > 0:
        player = Player(protocol, str(result[0]), str(result[1]), result[2])
        self.players.append(player)

    for player in self.players:
        id1 = str(player.playerId)
        id2 = str(playerId)
        print type(id1)
        print type(id2)
        print "Comparing '%s' with '%s'" % (id1, id2)

# HERE IS THE COMPARISON

        if id1 == id2:
            print "Equal! Player found!"
            return player
        else:
            print "Not equal :("
```

Give the following result:

```
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
Comparing '11111111' with '11111111'
Not equal :(
```

Comment: Use `%r` instead of `'%s'`. Perhaps some non-printable characters or lookalikes.

Comment: Seems like you are right, here's the new result: **Comparing ''11111111'' with ''11111111\x00''**. Do you know why this happen?

Comment: what was the type of playerID that was sent to the function? which python version?

Comment: As someone who uses Bash a lot my msitake was I put [ ] around the condition (facepalm emoji) as in if [ str =="[]" ] . Adding in case someone else needs this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to have a string processing error.
`PlayerId` seems to be a C-String being stored in a unicode String.

Background: `C` uses a nullbyte (`\x00`) to mark the end of a string. Since this nullbyte is in your string it ends up in the string representation of the object.

You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5559810/258418), for some reference. But without more code I am not sure about the cause/fix.

Have you tried `type(playerId)`?

*edit*: I don't know what python implementation you are using, for cpython look [here](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/strings.html)

Unfortunately I am not to firm in interfacing c and python, however you could try to use [`PyString_FromString`](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/string.html) to convert it on the c side to a python string or use some handcrafted function (eg split with regex at the first *unescaped* 0).

Some interfacing libs are listed in this [awnser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5960928/258418)

Comment: Right, actually the playerId is coming over the network from a C program. What would be the best way to remove that nullbyte terminator.

Comment: Actually I just removed the last char on the C side. Seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: Ok I was not sure if you have control over both sides, but as it turns out you do. Check out [`PyString_FromString`](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/string.html) anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You can strip any non-printable characters like so

```
import string
player = ''.join(filter(lambda c: c in string.printable, player))
```